# Running react unit test with scss

Tags: react-redux, enzyme, jestjs

I have a react component that is using a scss file.  The scss file is as follows

```
$searchImage: url('../../../stylesheets/images/Search.svg');
.srchBoxContaner {
    padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0rem 1.5rem;
}
```

The react component is a standard component that has the following import

```
import styles from './IncrementalSearch.scss';
```

I am using Jest, Enzyme, and Sinon.  My unit test is as follows

```
describe('<IncrementalSearch />', () => {
    it('calls componentDidMount', () => {
        sinon.spy(IncrementalSearch.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
        const wrapper = mount(<IncrementalSearch />);
        expect(IncrementalSearch.prototype.componentDidMount.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

When I run the test I get the following error

Unexpected token (2:0)
        1 | $searchImage: url('../../../stylesheets/images/Search.svg');

> 2 | .srchBoxContaner {
>             | ^
>           3 |     padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0rem 1.5rem;
>           4 | }

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't actually want to try loading the scss file in your test environment -- because when you do, Node will try to parse the scss file as javascript.

You need to mock out scss files in your test environment. You can use `moduleNameMapper` to do that: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string

e.g.

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/tests/config/jest/styleMock.js"
  },
```

**styleMock.js**

```
module.exports = {}
```